# Lazarus compiler stops everytime a procedure or a constructor of a class is called

Tags: pascal, lazarus

I've created a "Border" class in delphi. When i call the constructor of the class "Create" the compiler stops and shows me the constructor with a [green arrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfnyB.png). After this i can debug the program again and the compiler will go on. So my question here is: Why does the compiler stop and what can i do against it? There are no errors or anything. It will be very annoying if that happens every time while compiling. I hope you guys can help me. I am using the IDE "Lazarus". Thank you

```
unit Unit2;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

interface

uses
  Classes, SysUtils;


type
  TBorder = class
  private
    Left:integer;
    Right:integer;
    Top:integer;
    Bottom:integer;

  public
    constructor Create(l,r,t,b:integer);
    function getLeft(): integer;
    function getRight(): integer;
    function getTop(): integer;
    function getBottom(): integer;
  end;

implementation

constructor TBorder.Create(l,r,t,b:integer);
Begin
  Left:= l;
  Right:=r;
  Top:=t;
  Bottom:=b;
end;
```

Comment: Why does the title say "Delphi compiler" when you are actually using Lazarus? Anyway, it is not the compiler, but the debugger.

Comment: Check if you have a breakpoint on that line.

Comment: This is not the complete program, please show the class creation code.

Answer (score 0):

It is trivially easy to set a breakpoint in Lazarus. If you click on the left side of the source window (the frame) on a particular line of executable code, it will set a breakpoint there. Click on the marker on that line to remove the breakpoint. Lazarus will save breakpoints in the project file, so closing and reopening the project, or quitting Lazarus and restarting it won't remove them.

Answer (score -1):

That green line is caused by the debugger reaching a breakpoint. To solve the problem, disable the breakpoint.